# AlertDialog.Builder not being removed correctly

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

Following on from another question I have asked I have created a new class to have an AlertDialog.Builder. This is used in multi classes thoughtout my app. I am creating an object of the class in the class I am using then calling the show() method when needed. This appears correctly.

Trouble I have is as soon as I try and call the show() again I get the following Error :

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. 
You must call removeView() on the child's parent first
```

I am not 100% sure where I need to call this removeView or specifc view. Below is the code of the Dialog Class

```
public class CommentDialog {
    private final Context context;
    private final AlertDialog.Builder builder;    
    private String text;

    private EditText editText;

    public CommentDialog(Context context) {
        this.context = context;

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment_dialog, null);

        editText = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.comment_text);
        editText.setText(getCommentText());

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        builder.setView(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.round_comment_dialog, null));
        builder.setTitle(R.string.round_comment_title); 
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                               setCommentText(editText.getText().toString());

                           }
                        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {


                           }
                        });
        builder.create();
    }

    public void setCommentText(String pCommentText) {
        text = pCommentText;
    }

    public String getCommentText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void show() {
        builder.show();
    }


}
```

Thanks for your Time

**EDITTED**

added round_comment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:background="@drawable/border_main"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/comment_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="5" >
        </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

**EDITTED MK2**

Within the main class I am doing the following :

above contructor

```
private CommentDialog myDialog;
```

within the oncreate()

```
myDialog = new CommentDialog(this);
```

Then on a button press :

```
case R.id.round_comment_button:
            myDialog.setommentText(comentText);
            myDialog.show();

            roundComentText = myDialog.getRoundCommentText();

            break;
```

Comment: can you post your comment_dialog.xml ? It potentially may be a problem with your layout. Also which line is it complaining about?

Comment: added comment_dialog.xml

Comment: Well its not your round_comment.xml. Could you elaborate on where this is being use and in what context?

Comment: added in the code where I am calling the class / methods. Hope that helps. Thanks

Comment: myDialog.show();. basiclly when I try and click the button again it gives the error on the show() method

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6577/discussion-between-joxtraex-and-james-dudley)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are better off just having your class extend the Dialog class and building it and then showing it. Of course your views would be created in the constructor of your Dialog class. Because the Dialog does not have a Positive and Negative buttons available, you will have to create your own and set anonymous listeners for your Dialog to listen to them. Everything else should be easy.

Answer (score 0):

```
public CommentDialog(Context context) 
{
        this.context = context;
}


**Replace the constructor with Activity**

public CommentDialog(Activity activity) 
{
        this.activity= activity;
}
```

Comment: That still gives me the same error. Where do I add the remove view code and what would it look like. Thanks. also why change it to this?

Comment: Can u post what exception u are getting ??

Comment: As stated above "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first"

Answer (score 0):

Error is self explaining that a view whose "content view/ layout" you are setting already has its layout.
Can you please pull out the line at which this error is occuring from the log cat.
Then try to see if you are setting any layout/ view to any view in your code at that point.
If it is so, then call its removeView() prior to setting its content view/ layout.

Comment: It is Erroring on the show() method. I will edit the top post to show how I am calling it

Comment: can you please fetch the line number from the log cat, as I am sure this is not a big problem and can be solved easily.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
 protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
 switch (id) {
 case 0:
 return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
         .setIcon(R.drawable.icon)
         .setTitle(“This is a dialog with some simple text...”)
         .setPositiveButton(“OK”, new
    DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
    int whichButton)
 {
  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
  “OK clicked!”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
 })
       .setNegativeButton(“Cancel”, new
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
       int whichButton)
     {
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
      “Cancel clicked!”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  })
```

Comment: Do not understand how this would help. Thanks

Comment: Read the question before posting an answer.

Comment: error is "remove parent" for a view, not how to cancle /dismiss the dialog